# Comparing dates in sql updates no rows, no errors

Tags: sql

I want to update the fee_status column to Pending, if today's date is greater than fees paid_upto column 
below is the code which is not working:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["My conection string"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "update pat_regtrn set fee_status ='Pending' where getdate()>paid_upto";
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

This runs without error but does not update any rows.  Removing the where statement updates rows.

Comment: What's "not working" about it?

Comment: Possibly two n's in conn on 4th line.  Although that could be a typo.  Are you getting any error?

Comment: "*is not working*" is not an acceptable error description.

Comment: Complete this list of question points, and I bet you'll almost ALWAYS get a fast response:  1) The goal:  what is to be accomplished. 
2) Platform, development language/environment/tools, operating system, all w/ versions. 
3) Initial work -- tried so far. 
4) Sample code. 
5) Results (data). 
6) Messages (errors/warnings). 
7) Resolution work -- tried so far. 
8) Questions -- anything you'd like more information on -- details, principle or practice. 
9) Ideas -- where you think it might need to go next.  I'd say you've given us (1) and (4)... what do you say?

Comment: the query ends up with no error. and the 'n' in conn in 4th row is typo mistake, when i remove the where clause and execute, the column gets updated.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name "is not working" because i am not getting any error.

Comment: Your update is very helpful.  Like John, below, I'm wonder what paid_upto contains... could you (1) tell us what the datatype is, on `[pat_regtrn].[paid_upto]`, and (2) execute `select top 3 paid_upto from pat_regtrn`, in Mgmt Studio, and tell us what the result is?  Other questions... please confirm:  (3) is this SQL Server, (4) If so, what version of SQL Server (2000,2005,2008) is this?  (I'd also confirm whether this was .NET, with connection strings in web.config / app.config... but since you *ARE* getting results with no WHERE clause, that proves the connection strings are working.)

Answer (score 1):

Run the sql query manually against the db and see what happens.

For instance if using Microsoft SQL Server use Microsoft SQL Management Studio to run the query.

The db should tell you how many rows it updates.

I'm wondering if paid_upto really contains dates to compare.  A select using the same update query may also shed some light.

```
select fee_staus, paid_upto from pat_regtrn where getdate()>paid_upto
```

This will help you see what the db actually would be updating.

Comment: That select will also show error messages:  is there a problem with getdate() being compared with paid_upto?